# Need clarification as to why code is correct

Tags: javascript, typeof

```js
const isString = (a, b, c) => {
  if (((typeof a) == "string") && ((typeof b) == "string") && ((typeof c) == "string")) {
    return "strings";
  }
  return "not strings";
}
```

Why is the `=>` after the argument required in order for this to work? I got this test question correct via trial and error, but I don't understand *why* it doesn't work without `=>`.

Here are the instructions.

> Create a function called "isString" that takes 3 arguments (x1, x2, x3)
>
> - Check if each argument is a string using typeof.
> - If each argument is a string, return "strings".
> - If each argument is NOT a string, return "not strings".

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, remember to mark one of them as accepted. (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 2):

The => is the syntax for an arrow function

Comment: straight to the point.  Thank you, this makes sense.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `=>` operator is required because that is how javascript's syntax for anonymous functions works. This is creating a function equivilent to `isString(a,b,c) {...}`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: answers my question.  Thank you, was racking my brain trying to understand.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), the `=>` is indicating that it is part of an [`Arrow Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). The following two codes are equivalent as for the understanding of the two.

```js
// function declaration
function isString (a, b, c) {
  if (((typeof a) == "string") && ((typeof b) == "string") && ((typeof c) == "string")) {
    return "strings";
  }
  return "not strings";
}
```

```js
// arrow function declaration; can also use `var` instead of `const`
const isString = (a, b, c) => {
  if (((typeof a) == "string") && ((typeof b) == "string") && ((typeof c) == "string")) {
    return "strings";
  }
  return "not strings";
};
```

Comment: This drives it home for me, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Javascript. There are a few ways to declare a function in Javascript. One, is as you have done it

```
const myFunc = (params) => {
    // code
}
```

This is treating `myFunc` like any other name in Javascript needing to be assigned a value. Another more traditional way is:

```
function myFunc(params) {
    // code
}
```

Note that because you have the `=` after `isString`, the Javascript engine is expecting you to define it as in the first example.

Comment: Awesome! Did not know there were 2 ways to answer this.  Lots to learn.  Thank you for your detailed answer.  This helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could be helpful!